# Printing >, <, and % in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

Please help me with this.
How to print `>`, `<` and `%` in LaTeX.
Backslash doesn't seem to work!

Comment: `<` and `>` should be used in math mode; for printing % use `\%`

Comment: @Marco: `<` and `>` are not mentioned in that other question, are they?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Indeed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Also see [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764). Under [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), it yields `\textless`, `\textgreater` and `\%`.

Answer (score 9):

The glyphs `<` and `>` have usually no place in typeset text, except in mathematical formulas. In a math formula, `<` and `>` produce the right symbol:

```
$a<b$
```

will provide the right spacing and letter shape.

You can still get those glyphs in normal text with `\textless` and `\textgreater`, provided you load

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

However, I don't recommend using them outside math formulas. You might want to use `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` in text, that produce different glyphs

> 〈 and 〉

For these either you use math mode (they are called `\langle` and `\rangle`) or load

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

In order to print %, just type `\%`.

Comment: how would you print double && ? \&& not working...

Comment: @Nulle Did you try `\&\&`?

Comment: No i didn't and that worked! Thank you very much! :)